# Apache rewrite URL to be caught by AliasMatch

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I need mod_rewrite to re-map an incoming URL so that it gets caught by `AliasMatch`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/app/(.*)  ^/dev-dave/app/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/static/(.*) ^/dev-dave/static/$1



AliasMatch ^/(.*)/static/(.*)$ /var/www/html/cosmos/$1/dist/static/$2
AliasMatch ^/(.*)/app/(.*)$ /var/www/html/cosmos/$1/dist/index.html
<Directory /var/www/html/cosmos>
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Is this possible? I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main *server config* you should use the `PT` (`passthrough`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directives that you want to be caught by the `AliasMatch`. (The `PT` flag is implied in a *directory* context, so it would not be required on directives that appear later in your file, in the `<Directory>` container.)

From the [Apache docs for the `PT` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt):

> The target (or substitution string) in a RewriteRule is assumed to be a file path, by default. The use of the [PT] flag causes it to be treated as a URI instead. That is to say, the use of the [PT] flag causes the result of the RewriteRule to be passed back through URL mapping, **so that location-based mappings, such as Alias, Redirect, or ScriptAlias, for example, might have a chance to take effect**.
>
> If, for example, you have an Alias for /icons, and have a RewriteRule pointing there, you should **use the [PT] flag to ensure that the Alias is evaluated**.

---

> ```
>             RewriteEngine On
>         RewriteBase /
>         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> ```

*Aside:* Your *front controller*, defined later, is missing the `RewriteRule` directive?! So this won't do anything in its current state. However, it's also prone to error... if you later added a `RewriteRule` directive later in the `<Directory>` container then the preceding *conditions* will be (unexpectedly) applied.